# Trouble using drag down with formula offset

Tags: microsoft-excel

I've been struggling with the offset function and would like to ask for help.
I have a series of values entered on "Sheet 2" that I want to display in a table on "Sheet 1" and I want to be able to apply the formula and use the drag down function.

I want to be able to enter a formula in cell A12 in "Sheet 1" that will copy the value in cell B18 in Sheet 2, then I want to be able to drag down from A12 and copy the value from the cell in every other column in "Sheet 2" but always in row 18.

So when dragging the formula down from A12 in "Sheet 1":

```
A13 = D18 from sheet 2
A14 = F18 from sheet 2
A15 = H18 from sheet 2
A16 = J18 from sheet 2
......
and so on
```

Can you help me do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use INDEX.  Put this in A12 and copy down:

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!$18:$18,,(ROW(1:1)-1)*2+2)
```